# How to use the linear referencing plugin from QGIS with postGIS data?

Tags: qgis, postgis, linear-referencing

I need a guide how to use this plugin properly, I'm a newbie on PostGIS and I'm trying to use the **linear referencing plugin** of QGIS. I've created a database on postgreSQL with the postGIS extension and on QGIS with the Spit plugin I created a new connection with that DB. But, it generated some problems when it tries to connect, it says: **fe_sendauth: no password supplied**. But, I decided to save the username and the password when I made the connection and that problem it isn't showed.

So, in the next step I tried the plugin, with the **configure** tool, it show **Connection OK, metadata OK**. Then I go to **Calibrate route**, and as it's showed[image: on the image below]

It stops the calculation on the fourth step, and I don't know why. What do I need to have on each Attribute table to this works properly, or what do I do wrong?

Comment: The point layer must have at least 2 attributes: one for line id and one for measure (like meter or kilometer) of the line at that point.

Comment: You can use LRS plugin, only available for QGIS 2.0 or upper.

Comment: +1 for using LRS, which allows you to work with QGIS layers and doesn't require PostGIS databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TESTED USING THE LRS PLUGIN VER 0.3.6

Your problem may be that you need to update your plugin/QGIS version
This is from the changelog of the LRS plugin:
changelog:
**0.3.6
- Fixed issue #6 (PostGIS data types not supported by memory provider)**

Your point files needs to have an attribute for distance along the line.  It also needs a route ID field.  Your line file needs to have the same route ID field and attributes as your point file.

1. Set your line and point layers and set your route field in LRS.
2. Set your measure field - MAKE SURE TO SET THE MEASURE UNIT TO CORRECT UNIT
3. Set the drop-down to 'Include routes' and select your route
4. Set the max distance of the points from the line (units are meters)

Hit OK and the calibration should work.